# Damage differences in frontal collision of two vehicles and their speed

Tags: dynamics

Please check this newspaper article and its pictures and the video in it: [Article](http://ilpiccolo.gelocal.it/trieste/cronaca/2016/08/17/news/panico-sul-tram-di-opicina-9-feriti-nello-scontro-frontale-1.13972540#gallery-slider=undefined)

It contains photos and a video of a frontal crash between two vehicles of a trolley line. From the photos, it seems like one vehicle suffered much more damage the the other. Judging by this photos, what can be said about the speed of the two vehicles? Can the difference in damage be attributed to much different speeds of the two vehicles?

Comment: Maybe one of them had much stronger... armor. :-)

Comment: No, as far as I know the vehicles should be identical.

Comment: Even if the two vehicles *were* "identical", as soon as *one* of them starts to crumple the situation is no longer symmetrical, and it's quite likely that they will end up with significantly different amounts of damage.

Answer (score 1):

The imact energy is the sum of the individual energies just prior to impact.

The damage to the fastest is not greater and vice versa - the relative damage is down to things like:

Older or newer designs ie crush zones.

The age ie effects of corrosion or previous damage on strength.

The angle of impact

The point of impact - can be a stronger impact point on one cf the other..

Many factors influence the level of damage.

Comment: "The impact energy is the sum of the individual energies just prior to impact."  In Newtonian mechanics, there isn't any consistent measurement of "kinetic energy" so that statement is  hard to apply in practice. For example, what is the difference between a rear-end collision of a vehicle travelling at 1 mph into a stationary vehicle, compared with a vehicle travelling at 101 mph rear-ending a vehicle travelling at 100 mph? Common sense says the damage is not going to be 10,000 times greater in the second case, even though the KE measured as "$mv^2/2$" is 10,000 times bigger.

Comment: @alephzero are you taking the direction into account?

Answer (score 0):

> Can the difference in damage be attributed to much different speeds of the two vehicles?

Which speed? If the cars hit each other, then there is only one speed that matters - the speed of car A relative to car B. This also means that the speed for both cars is the **same**.

If one car is moving at 30 km/h, and the other is moving the other direction at 60 km/h, then they collide at a relative speed of 90 km/h. You **cannot** analyze the collision with individual speeds.

Consider the alternative - if you yourself are standing still (0 km/h), and a truck hits you going 100 km/h, do you suffer any damage? Your speed was zero, correct? Was this a low speed collision for you?

Comment: What happens if the car doing 60 km/h runs into the back of the car doing 30 km/h? I suggest the resulting speed is the difference...

Comment: @SolarMike - I clarified the post but that's what I opened with - there is only one speed that matters - the difference between the two cars. Their speed relative to a stop doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

As Solar Mike said, from theoretical physics point of view, there's no difference: A impacts B with exactly the same force as B impacts A.

There are finer details though, that come out from minor asymmetries.

- Due to wear and aging, no two parts are identical.
- Material that started buckling will continue to buckle. So if the weaker parts gives in first, it will give in all the way before the stronger part starts sustaining damage; the split isn't equal or proportional to strength of materials - even slightly stronger wins by a large margin.
- Material reinforced by frame is tougher than separated from the frame.

Here, it seems like the cars have very solid undercarriage; their frames didn't buckle, but one lifted above the other, and plowed into the structure of the other car, ripping the chassis away, and supporting own chassis which continued to plow into the weakened counterpart.